# Altering Physics Property of a Shape in Unity

Tags: unity, physics

I want to create say 4 blocks, and each block will dictate how e.g. the bounciness of an object landing on it will behave. So if the block is made of sand, I don't want bounciness, if the block is wood I want it to bounce, if it's ice block i want it to bounce a bit and then slide for X amount of time. How can I adjust the physics of the object landing on that block based on what block it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create four GameObjects.  Add a Collider to each GameObject.  Set the physics material of each Collider.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html

Set the bounciness to the value you want in the Physics Material.  Each GameObject would have it's own physics material with specific bounciness.

Comment: No problem.  Keep in mind you should use values between 0 and 1 for the bounciness, as indicated in the linked docs.  Good luck.